# Using default ShapeDrawable in a StateListDrawable in Android 4.2

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Anyone else got problems using a new `ShapeDrawable()` in a `StateListDrawable` in android 4.2? I used to do this:

```
ShapeDrawable bg = new ShapeDrawable();    //default Ctor
ShapeDrawable hl = new ShapeDrawable();
hl.getPaint().setColor(color1);
bg.getPaint().setColor(color2);

StateListDrawable s1 = new StateListDrawable();
s1.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, hl);
s1.addState(new int[]{}, bg);
```

But this doesn't work anymore in Android **4.2**, throwing a `nullpointerexception` :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable.mutate(ShapeDrawable.java:387)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.selectDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:315)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.onStateChange(StateListDrawable.java:106)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.addState(StateListDrawable.java:89)
```

I fixed the issue by changing the constructor of my `ShapeDrawable`:

```
ShapeDrawable bg = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
ShapeDrawable hl = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
```

Now **this works great**, but I would like to know **why this didn't work with the default constructor** =)

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `DrawableContainer.selectDrawable()` realization has changed in Android 4.2 and the `ShapeDrawable` must use construct with args.

If you use default constructor ,when invoke `mutate()` `mShape` is `null` ,so mShape.clone() will throw `CloneNotSupportedException` and return `null`. so you get a `NullPointerException`.